# Is it possible to use Spring Data JPA projections together with QueryDSL?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

Is there a way in  Spring Data JPA to combine out of box its support for QueryDSL and Projections (projections being inferred from the defined classes/interfaces).

Even though I read [here and there](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2090#issuecomment-1151115325) that the support was added in 2.6 (the version I am using in the project) I am not able to make it work with various attempts like:

1. Using projection type as `QuerydslPredicateExecutor` type parameter.
   Problem: the returned instances are of the entity class type not of the projection class type.
2. Using `findAllProjectedBy`. Problem: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least 1 parameter(s) provided but only 0 parameter(s) present in query.` on startup (repo creation phase).

```
public interface FooRepo extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<FooProjection> { //(1)
    
    
    List<FooProjection> findAllProjectedBy(Predicate p); //(2)

}
```

Spring Data JPA version - 2.6.1.

I saw also some SO answers with custom solutions but I am not interested in that approach (some even use deprecated Spring Data JPA implementation components).

Comment: What does not work? Do you get an exception?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I added the problem description to the both cases.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74016491/dynamic-projection-with-spring-jpa-repository-and-query-dsl/74025775#74025775